# MVC 4 pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the extract of my code and the error which I am facing. Can anyone please help me.

```
var rentList = from s in db.TANK_LEASE_DETAILs
               join tm in db.TANK_MASTERs on s.TANK_MASTER_ID equals tm.TANK_ID
               select new { s,tm };

tanks = rentList.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
```

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'MvcPaging.IPagedList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

what is the type of your tanks variable? as error message imply, it is IList not IPagedList.

you should change the type of tanks to IPagedList, or use var:

```
var tanks = rentList.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
```